# Python, Function is not being called randomly

Tags: python

I've finished writing the rock scissors or paper program. I have a function ai() that deciding for the computer side with random. This function also prints the decision of the computer which I call every time loop finishes, however, sometimes it's just no doing it. Can you please help me figure out why? Any improvement advices much appraciated

**This is my function**

```
def ai():
    number = random.randint(1,4)
    if number == 1:
        global aiinput
        aiinput = ("rock")
        print(("The choice of computer is: "),aiinput)
    elif number == 2:
        aiinput = ("paper")
        print(("The choice of computer is: "),aiinput)
    elif number == 3:
        aiinput = ("scissors")
        print(("The choice of computer is: "),aiinput)
```

**And this is the rest of my code**

```
import random

def ai():
    number = random.randint(1,4)
    if number == 1:
        global aiinput
        aiinput = ("rock")
        print(("The choice of computer is: "),aiinput)
    elif number == 2:
        aiinput = ("paper")
        print(("The choice of computer is: "),aiinput)
    elif number == 3:
        aiinput = ("scissors")
        print(("The choice of computer is: "),aiinput)

def draw():
    print ("Draw")
def loser():
    print ("Loser!")
def winner():
    print ("You won!")

print("Welcome to the game to quit prompt q")
while True:
    usrinp = input("rock, scissors or paper? you can also prompt r,s or p: ")
    ai()
    if usrinp == ("r") and aiinput == ("rock"):
        draw()
    elif usrinp == ("r") and aiinput == ("paper"):
        loser()
    elif usrinp == ("r") and aiinput == ("scissors"):
            winner()


    if usrinp == ("p") and aiinput == ("rock"):
        winner()
    elif usrinp == ("p") and aiinput == ("paper"):
        draw()
    elif usrinp == ("p") and aiinput == ("scissors"):
        loser()

    if usrinp == ("s") and aiinput == ("rock"):
        loser()
    elif usrinp == ("s") and aiinput == ("paper"):
        winner()
    elif usrinp == ("s") and aiinput == ("scissors"):
        draw()
    if usrinp == ("q"):
        quit()
```

Here as you can see debug
[debug results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAlPx.png)

Comment: I believe the only time it doesn't print anything is when `random.randint(1,4)` return value **4**. Either add `elif` case to check for *4* or better yet add `else` clause because you only it can only be **4**.

Comment: https://trinket.io/python/a754d32c7b

Comment: Thank you for pointing out appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only set `global aiinput` after a `if` in your `ai` function. Do it before the ifs. You also need to use `randint(1, 3)`.

```
def ai():
    global aiinput # This goes before the conditions.      
    aiinput = {1: "rock",
               2: "paper",
               3: "scissors"}[random.randint(1, 3)]
    print("The choice of computer is: ", aiinput)
```

Answer (score 0):

You generate the value 1-4 and only check 1-3 so if its 4 it will do nothing
Below is an example:

```
Return a number between 3 and 9 (both included):

import random

print(random.randint(3, 9))
```

Comment: oh, I thought it's up 4 to but not including the 4 itself.I've changed to 3 now I guess it works thank you ^^

Comment: if your problem is solved please accept the answer that solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 reasons:
Firstly, as @Rolandas Ulevicius said, your random number function can produce numbers that are not handled by the if statements; see the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint).

Secondly, in your function `ai()`, you define the global variable `aiinput` only when the ai picks 1, i.e. rock. A better way of doing this would be to define a local variable inside of the function, and returning the value. In your case, the implementation would look a little something like:

```
def ai():
    number = random.randint(1,3)
    if number == 1:
        print("The choice of computer is: rock")
        return "rock"
    elif number == 2:
        print("The choice of computer is: paper")
        return "paper"
    elif number == 3:
        print("The choice of computer is: scissor")
        return "scissors"
```

and then in the while loop, you would change `ai()` to `aiinput = ai()`

There are better ways of doing the code but as you appear to be fairly beginner, I won't include them, unless you specifically want them.

EDIT: See @Guimoute's answer for a better way to structure `ai()`